# Algebraic Closures are Splitting Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, field-theory, galois-theory

Assuming that $\overline{K}$ is an algebraic closure of the field $K$, how would one go about proving that $\overline{K}$ must be a splitting field?

I am trying to do this by finding a set $\mathcal{P}$ of polynomials such that $\overline{K}$ is a splitting field of $\mathcal{P}$ over $K$.

Comment: Hint: what's the splitting field of $K[x]$ over $K$?

Comment: This will be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838832/linking-two-theorems-on-algebraic-closure-and-on-minimal-splitting-field